# autocomplete of imported packages not working

Tags: python, autocomplete, jupyter-notebook

I am relative new to Python and Jupyter notebook. At the moment I am struggling with the autocompletion in Jupyter notebook which would increase my learning hopefully.

The problem is the following:
Autocomplete works when I am running 
`import pan <hit tab here>` and it autocompletes to `import pandas`   I finish the line then by `import pandas as pn`

However, if I now want to invove a function of the pandas package lets say `pn. <and hit tab here>` there are no suggestions for autocomplete. Nothing, also not after waiting some time.

When I start Python over the command line and then do the same as described above - it works, and I get the autocomplete suggestions...
The tricky thing is that I am running a virtual machine with a preinstalled Python and Jupyter notebook over a cloud computing provider. Happy if someone has some suggestions or ideas, workarounds
Thank you,